# How to set alternate IPV4 configuration to static address

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, .net-4.0

With the network adaptor set as a DHCP client, how can I set the alternate configuration address to a static value, instead of the default APIPA, from within my VB.NET program?

[image]

I have already configured all the other setting for the interface using System.Management.ManagementClass and WMI, here is an example:

```
Private Function EnableDHCP(mac As String) As Integer

    Dim retval As Integer = 200 
    Dim mc As New System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
    Dim moc As ManagementObjectCollection = mc.GetInstances


    For Each mo As ManagementObject In moc
        If mo("MACAddress") = mac Then
            If mo("IPEnabled") Then 
                retval = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", Nothing)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return retval

End Function
```

But I can find no WMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration method or property that sets the alternate configuration when DHCP is enabled.

I found [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=apipa_vbs) example script that operates on registry settings but a search on the dev machine registry can find no "IPAutoconfigurationEnabled" key or value.

Thanks in advance.